# Creating a secured Symfony2 project where every single page redirects to a login until user is authenticated

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I'd like to create a project that forces any and all users to log in before seeing anything on the website; any pages they visit will redirect them to the login form until they complete it successfully. My current security.yml setup is:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout: true
            anonymous: true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

If I change "anonymous" to false, I get a redirect loop on any page I try to visit, including /login. Is there a proper way to get to what I'm trying to accomplish?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be missing:

```
- { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

From the access control list:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

The access_control list is in order of precedence so `- { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }` is a catchall. This should secure all paths which are not /login, /register, /resetting or admin.

Comment: Exactly what I was missing. Thanks for your help.